# What is the difference between TF Learn (aka Scikit Flow) and TFLearn (aka TFLearn.org)

Tags: frameworks, tensorflow, skflow

There are two TFLearn projects

```
TF Learn (aka Scikit Flow)
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn
```

and

```
TFLearn: Deep learning library featuring a higher-level API for TensorFlow.
https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn
```

what is the status of these projects, are they going to stay separate or they going to merged together?

Comment: Probably separate, due to Conway's Law

Comment: Alright, I was hoping that since they were named the same and seem to serve similar purposes that one would be deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

[TF.Learn](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn) is a built-in module inside TensorFlow built by Googlers and outside contributors. It's originally called skflow (Scikit Flow). It is for both deep learning as well as general machine learning. You can find the official tutorials on TensorFlow website.

Comment: Now TF.Learn is renamed to be TensorFlow Estimators under `tf.estimator`. You can check our KDD paper for more details of the architectural design here: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3098171

Answer (score 3):

Tflearn is actually a separate package, which doesn't come with the standard tensorflow distribution. One needs to do `pip install tflearn` to actually install it. It seems the models included in `tflearn` are very limited  (mainly DNN) but no linear classifiers for example, whereas tf.contrib.learn has more models, e.g.:

```
tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier
```

Comment: Is there any difference between a linear model and a neural network with one parametric layer and the identity as activation function?